# Am I using my data source array correctly?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

When I want to make some quick tests for my UITableViewControllers, I usually create an NSArray that holds some dummy data. I would like to know if I'm doing anything wrong here:

First in `MasterViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataSourceArray;

@end
```

and then in `MasterViewController.m`:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize dataSourceArray = _dataSourceArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        _dataSourceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"obj 1", @"obj 2", @"obj 3", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_dataSourceArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So, the real question, as long as I'm **not** assigning `_dataSourceArray` to something else, I'm safe in terms of memory management here, right?

Comment: I agree, the code looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Everything seems correct here.

Like you mention yourself: make sure you use `self.dataSourceArray` to assign new values, and the synthesized setter will take care of memory management.